# Multiprocessing on pandas dataframe. Confusing behavior based on input size

Tags: python, pandas, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to implement an df.apply like function but parallelized across chunks of the dataframe. I wrote the following test code to see how much I could gain (versus data copying etc):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
from functools import partial
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import time

def df_apply(df, f):
    return df.apply(f, axis=1)

def apply_in_parallel(df, f, n=5):
    pool = Pool(n)
    df_chunks = np.array_split(df, n)
    apply_f = partial(df_apply, f=f)
    result_list = pool.map(apply_f, df_chunks)
    return pd.concat(result_list, axis=0)

def f(x):
  return x+1

if __name__ == '__main__':
  N = 10^8
  df = pd.DataFrame({"a": np.zeros(N), "b": np.zeros(N)})

  print "parallel"
  t0 = time.time()
  r = apply_in_parallel(df, f, n=5)
  print time.time() - t0

  print "single"
  t0 = time.time()
  r = df.apply(f, axis=1)
  print time.time() - t0
```

Weird behavior:
for N=10^7 it works
for N=10^8 it gives me an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parallel_apply.py", line 27, in <module>
    r = apply_in_parallel(df, f, n=5)
  File "parallel_apply.py", line 14, in apply_in_parallel
    result_list = pool.map(apply_f, df_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 227, in map
    return self.map_async(func, iterable, chunksize).get()
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 528, in get
    raise self._value
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?
I'd also appreciate any feedback on this way of parallelizing. I am expecting functions that take more time than inc or sum per individual row and millions of rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

`array_split` accepts any array-like argument (including `pandas.DataFrame` objects), but only returns guarantees that it return a `numpy.ndarray` (which DataFrames are *not*). Of course, ndarrays don't have an `apply` method, which is exactly the error you're seeing. I'm actually surprised that this works in any scenario. You'll either need to split the dataframe into sub-frames or apply a function that operations on ndarrays.

Answer (score 1):

`N = 10^8` results `2`, `N = 10^7` results `13`, because the operator `^` is XOR (not power). So a 2 row length df can not be splitted into 5 chunks. Use this instead: `N = 10**4` and `N = 10**5`. With these values you will see the difference in time. Be careful with values greater than `N = 10**6` (at this value the parallel time is at about 30 sec, single time is at about 167 sec). And use `pool.close()` at the end (before `return`) in `apply_in_parallel()` to automatically close all workers in the pool.